# How to create family relation logic?

Tags: sql, neo4j, prolog, logic, graph-theory

I'm trying to make [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=father%27s%20sister%27s%20grandfather&dataset=&equal=Submit) but for a different language. In this language there are different kinds of names for uncles and aunts. We call paternal aunt something else and maternal aunt something else.

I came across a graph database 'neo4j'. I created 5 members. I got this approach to work just like I want. But the problem in this is that I've to create `n * (n-1)` relationships. I'm create a full tree here and not just 5 members of a family.

Also, this is more like brute force. I'm creating all the possibilities. 
[image]

I'm looking for a smarter way to do this. Creating rules like for example `Father's sister = paternal-aunt` and `Mother's sister = maternal-aunt`
I also want queries `Father's wife's sister` but don't want to define them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can create functions that establish the rules, e.g.:

```
def is_maternal_aunt(individual, member):
    return member in individual.mother.sister
```

These can be arbitrary complex:

```
def is_maternal_aunt(individual, member):
    return is_sister(individual.mother, member)

def is_sister(individual, member):
    return individual.mother == member.mother
```

It will be a matter of design for which you consider are primary relationships and which are derived. You can probably derive everything from parent child relationships (and marriage).

Comment: My input will be anything like for eg. "father wife sister". Which should return maternal aunt. What should be the class structure of individual and member?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create the bidirectional relationships, and you also don't have to create short-cut-relationships, you can just infer the information in the other direction or across multiple steps.

```
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((p1:Person {name:"Jane"})-[*]-(p2:Person {name:"John"}))
RETURN [r in relationships(path) | type(r)] as rels
```

which would then return ["husband","father"] e.g. for an Father-in-Law
or ["mother","sister"] for an maternal aunt.

You can then map those tuples either still in cypher (with `case`) or in your python program.

Comment: What do you mean by bidirectional relationships and short-cut relationships?
I'm not very clear. Can you please explain or link me to something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is a reasonable choice... For instance I have this [small library](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/tree/master/genealogy) to draw 'genealogy trees' like this

[image]

from this definition (genre definitions are used only to change node' color)

```
:- module(elizabeth, [elizabeth/0]).
:- use_module(genealogy).

elizabeth :- genealogy(elizabeth, 'Elizabeth II Family').

female('Elizabeth II').
female('Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon').
female('Princess Mary of Teck').
female('Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck').

parent_child('George VI', 'Elizabeth II').
parent_child('Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon','Elizabeth II').

parent_child('George V', 'George VI').
parent_child('Princess Mary of Teck', 'George VI').

parent_child('Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon').
parent_child('Claude Bowes-Lyon', 'Lady Elizabeth Bowes-Lyon').
```

It requires SWI-Prolog and Graphviz.

*edit* adding some facts

```
female('Rose Bowes-Lyon').
parent_child('Cecilia Cavendish-Bentinck','Rose Bowes-Lyon').
parent_child('Claude Bowes-Lyon', 'Rose Bowes-Lyon').
```

and the rule

```
is_maternal_aunt(Person, Aunt) :-
    parent_child(Parent, Person),
    female(Parent),
    parent_child(GranParent, Parent),
    parent_child(GranParent, Aunt),
    Aunt \= Parent.
```

we get

```
?- is_maternal_aunt(X,Y).
X = 'Elizabeth II',
Y = 'Rose Bowes-Lyon' ;
```

Comment: How can I query something like what's my relation to 'father's father's daughter'?

Comment: The main relation is parent_child/2. I introduced female/1 facts, so we *could* introduce a rule `male(X) :- \+ female(X).`. Then, every other relation can be computed. i.e. `father(Father,Child) :- parent_child(Father,Child), male(Father).` Using negation to define facts  has some consequence about computability...

Comment: Thanks for replying. Appreciate it. But I'm not asking how to define relationship for father. Input of my program can be anything like 'sister's brother's father's father' which should return grandfather. How to compute that?

Comment: Prolog has a relational data model... just write down the join, it becomes a rule. Such join would require adding sister/2, brother/2, and, of course, father/2

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. Do you think for replicating [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=father%27s%20sister%27s%20grandfather&dataset=&equal=Submit) prolog is a good idea? A user can input anything and it returns a relation.

Comment: I don't know Wolfram Alpha, so I cannot be sure... Prolog it's for *computing logic*, and of course this doesn't comprises *anything*. Knowledge representation and computability have strong and complex relationships... Usually, we go thru 'googling' for answers, isn't true ? and then we apply *our* knowledge about the world...

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764537/another-relationship-as-argument-to-a-relationship-in-prolog)?

Comment: @RaghavSharma: the answer you got there it's fine... relational calculus is applied. As I said above, its data model is relational, with only limited support - for instance - arithmetic, that is cumbersome when expressed in pure relational form

Comment: All right thanks, man! I've bothered you enough. I'll take it from here.