# Another rule as argument to a rule in prolog

Tags: prolog

This is my prolog file.

```
male(bob).
male(john).

female(betty).
female(dana).

father(bob, john).
father(bob, dana).
mother(betty, john).
mother(betty, dana).

daughter(X, Y) :- female(X), mother(Y, X).
```

I want to query something like this `daughter(X, mother(Y, john)).`
Is it possible?

I'm trying to get daughter of john's mother.

I got this idea from [here](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/cs9414/notes/prolog/intro.html) under 'Asking Questions with Structures'

Comment: if it is ok, could you mark as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
daughter(X, Y), mother(Y, john).
```

This will match Y as the mother of john and then X as the daughter of Y. So X will be the daughter of john mother.

Comment: Yeah, that would do. Thanks!
Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770849/given-values-x-and-y-return-rule-name-if-it-is-true)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mothers_daughter(X, Y) :- mother(Z,X), daughter(Y,Z).
```

query -> `mothers_daughter(john, Y).`

**EDIT:** daughter(X, mother(Y, Z)):- female(X),mother(Y, X).

Comment: Like I mentioned I want it to call like this `daughter(X, mother(Y, john)).` Is it possible to do something like that without defining a separate relation? I'm trying to replicate [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mother%27s+daughter)

Comment: I got idea from [here](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/cs9414/notes/prolog/intro.html). Under section 'Asking Questions with Structures'. `owns(john, book(Title, author(leguin, GivenName))).`

Comment: like ? daughter(X, mother(Y, Z)):- female(X),mother(Y, X).

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer I really appreciate it. But it isn't what I want. I don't want to create a new rule. I'm gonna wait for few more hours. If nothing, will accept yours.